# Fetch a particular value from live updating cell values in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have API functions in my excel that fetch live stock prices. I want to save the first live price at 9:15 am in a column, but as this value is fetched through a function, I am unable to modify another cell value. I tried calling subroutine inside the function, but it crashes the excel.

How can this be achieved?

I want the value exactly at 9:15 and not the values before or after that.

Can something like DictKeys be used?

**My Code**

```
Public Function GetRTD(Exch As String, TrdSymbol As String, Field As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Exch = "" Then
        GetRTD = ""
        Exit Function
    End If
    If TrdSymbol = "" Then
        GetRTD = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim Prfx As String
    Prfx = TrdSymbol & "." & Exch

    GetRTD = WorksheetFunction.RTD("Kite.RtdServer", "", Prfx, Field)
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: Please provide the code you have come up with so far.

Comment: I tried using the following options:

-ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Details").Cells(2, 26).Value = <value>

-Calling a subroutine inside the function

But both these option give #NAME error

Comment: This is my function code:
Public Function GetRTD(Exch As String, TrdSymbol As String, Field As String)
On Error Resume Next
If Exch = "" Then
GetRTD = ""
Exit Function
End If

If TrdSymbol = "" Then
GetRTD = ""
Exit Function
End If

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Prfx As String
Prfx = TrdSymbol & "." & Exch

GetRTD = WorksheetFunction.RTD("Kite.RtdServer", "", Prfx, Field)
Exit Function

End Function

Comment: If I really understand your question you are using this function on a worksheet as a formula (UDF) then you need to: 1. Add another parameter to your function to a dummy cell and use it in your formula | 2. Make a subroutine that calls another subroutine at 09:15 with Application.OnTime TimeValue("09:15:00"), "my_subroutine" ([Application.OnTime ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-ontime-method-excel)) | 3. The called subroutine changes the dummy cell to make your function update (an UDF) as a formula only updates if a value changes

Comment: I tried to call a subroutine in the function. But as the function is called frequently to fetch live ticks. Hence the excel crashes. Is there any other approach? Can we use concept like DictKeys here?